# JUnit 5 and Test Suites

Tags: java, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

We have a pure JUnit-5 project and we want to categories our unit tests.

To do so, what I understand is we need to include the JUnit-4 `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`.

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeTags;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("my.project.domain")
@IncludeTags("long-running-test") 
public interface LongRunningTestSuite {}
```

In Intellij-Idea I can run all or just test suites without problems but I get an error on the execution with maven:

- in Intellij-Idea some test cases fail
- on the console I have an endless loop

This didn't help:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*TestSuite.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java, **/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I just remove all the `XyzTestSuite.java` classes the maven build is successful. I also tried `<exclude>my.project.domain.testsuite</exclude>`.

The exclution seams not to work. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JUnitPlatform` has been deprecated.

The corresponding new feature is the *JUnit Platform Suite Engine*. See [JUnit 5 User Guide: 6.2. JUnit Platform Suite Engine](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/index.html#junit-platform-suite-engine).

However, if it’s just about categorizing tests, tags, which are much simpler, might be sufficient. See [JUnit 5 User Guide: 2.9 Tagging and Filtering](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering).

Comment: I changed the dependencies as mentioned in those links but still doesn't work: `mvn test -Dtest=my.project.domain.MyTestSuite`. It says _no tests were executed_. I'm using tags to group my tests.

Comment: Have you also added the Suite annotation?

Comment: Yes: 
`import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeClassNamePatterns;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;

@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName("Integration Tests")
@SelectPackages("my.domain")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns(".*ITTest")
public interface IntegrationTestSuite {}`

Comment: OK, I had to change the TestSuits from interface to class that all works as before in Intellij-Idea but it still doesn't work with maven.

Comment: I realized that this is just a local problem. On Jenkins this error doesn't appear.